# Convert json into separate object using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to convert my json into separate object. I'm able to convert `status`, `code`, & `Desc` but when I try converting `errors` I'm getting:

> [ Argument must not be null or empty. ]

I want to have `errors` without the brackets so that it is text only.

My Json:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "warnings": {
        "Code": "VALIDATION",
        "Desc": "Invalid inputs",
        "errors": [
            "Argument must not be null or empty."
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
 print(response.text)
 tmp = json.loads(response.text)
 print(tmp['status'])
 temp = (tmp['warnings'])
 t1 = temp['Code']
 t2 = temp['Decription']
 t3 = temp['errors']
 print(t1)
 print(t2)
 print(t3)
```

Can Someone please correct me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you are looking for:

```py
tmp = json.loads(response.text)
tmp = tmp["warnings"]
t1 = tmp['Code']
t2 = tmp['Desc']
t3 = tmp['errors'][0]
print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```